# CodeIgniter: Cannot set_userdata

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session

My codeigniter app is a subdomain of wordpress site.

When I set a session, it's not working.

I already autoloaded the session library and trace other possible problems.

The problem is that `$this->session->set_userdata()` seems to not work.

Comment: check for this poins

$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/'; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;

Folder permissions 0700

Comment: @romanreign what do you mean by this? current session config does not have that config.

Comment: @Owen Bula Is the sub-domain folder located outside of wordpress? or is it located inside the wordpress directory? Have you set the $config['base_url'] to the sub-domain?

Comment: @Amila under public_html > wordpress folders + codeigniter_folder

Comment: what is your sub-domain permission?

Comment: @romanreign 0755

Comment: @Owen Bula how do you access two sites? the urls as an example?

Comment: @amila If I want to acces the wp, I use wordpress.com, on the other hand, I access the ci app using wordpress.com/crm

Comment: @OwenBula Have you made any changes to session config at config.php or left it with defaults? And also check to see if you are getting ci_session cookie in your browser.

Comment: @AmilaDev configs are still the same and i'm getting the ci_session.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your cookie config as follows and see if it works:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.yourdomain.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/crm';
```

If it still doesn't work you can try configuring CI to save the session data in the database instead of disk.

Also make sure your $config['base_url'] is set to http://yourdomain.com/crm/

You should also have an .htaccess in your crm directory and it should contain below lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /crm/
```